# resize portionally image and center in container

Tags: css, css-position, image-gallery, resize-image

I want to display my image in full-width Gallery.
The container is static:

```
#container{
    width:100%;
    height:400px;
}

<div id="container">
   <img src="myimage.jpg">
</div>
```

I have images of different dimensions, so I want display the image in full width without deformate this in height, but centering the image (in height way) to diplay it in the center.

Comment: Can you set the image to background image? if so you can give it `background-size:cover;` and `background-position:50% 50%;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep the same aspect ratio but your images are different dimensions your best solution would be as Patsy Issa is saying.

Use css

```
#myimage{
    background: url("myimage.jpg") no-repeat center center; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    width:100%;
    height:400px;
}
```

And HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="myimage"></div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qBPy6/